# ISA - Why do i suddenly need to specify settings on the client machines?

Tags: windows-server-2003, isa-server

Have been pulling my hair out over this one for hours, and wondering if someone can help.
I have a server with two network interfaces that was running isa 2004 and humming until i installed sbs service pack + isa 2004 service pack 3.  Grrrrrrrrrr

I can get the client machines to connect to the internet but only by installing the ISA Client on each machine or setting proxy settings etc in the internet settings.

Ideally i want the client machines to just work with no configuration or proxy server settings as they were before.

Where do i start, and what other information do you need from me if any to find out what im doing wrong

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What are the settings in IE wich did work without the SP3 for ISA2004? If autodiscover proxy settings is enabled, then it looks like the WPAD-configuration is broken. This is a feature to auto-detect the proxy-settings by requesting wpad.dat from your isa-server.

Check if you can get a file named http://wpad/wpad.dat. If that doesn't work, check if there is a dns-name WPAD pointing to your isa-server, and check if you can get the file using http://isa-server/wpad.dat.

More info about WPAD: 
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713344.aspx

Comment: hi thanks for the answer i think autodiscover was on and that is all. do i replace "isa-server" with the actual internal full domain name of my server?

Comment: jup, you should replace it with the name of FQDN of your isa-server. If that works, check if a DNS-entry (A-record) WPAD exists, and points to the IP of your ISA-server.